# Returning additional lines of data based on a where clause in a union query

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a single table with all of the sales information.
Sometimes a sale can be credited to 2 sales people causing a value of .5
When that happens I need to have the half sale reported in 2 places.
The report would look like this

```
Salesman   Salesman 2   Unit No  Unit Cnt.   Date 
====================================================
Dave S.     N/A         HTU88       1        8/2/16
Dave S.     Phil N.     NC88y      .5        8/5/16
Total Sales.....................: 1.5

Phil N.     N/A         JKI98u      1        8/1/16
Phil N.     N/A         JI98u1      1        8/3/16
Phil N.     Dave S.     NC88y      .5        8/5/16
Total Sales.....................: 2.5

Store Total.....................: 4.0
```

Comment: That's great. Do you have a question?

Comment: That seems like something you'd do on a report end of things more than in SQL itself (it's certainly possible to do in SQL, just not optimal IMO)

Comment: If you have a good database design, it should not be a problem, if not, can you provide your table(s) schema? How do you store data? in one table? or more? BTW, is it sql-server or mysql?  these 2 tags are different.